# Tkinter Accessing Variables from Different Function

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to access variables from different files if the widget is an Entry? I have tried using the command option but found that was exclusive to Buttons. I'm trying to separate my functions into different files to modulate.

```
ttk.Label(root, text="How many points do you want to input:").pack()
cell_content = StringVar()
cell_content.trace_add("write", my_tk.retrieve_cell_content)
cell_content_entry = Entry(root, width = 8, textvariable = cell_content)
cell_content_entry.pack()


tkinterFunctions.py
def retrieve_cell_col(self, *args):
    global CELL_COL
    temp = cell_col.get()
    temp = temp.upper()
```

Comment: This code won't run for a variety of reasons. Please post a working [mcve]. There's nothing special about an `Entry` widget, it's no different than any other python object with respect to accessing it in other files.

Comment: Different functions can access variables regardless of what they contain (such as a tkinter `Entry` widget). However, if they (the functions) are defined in separate modules, then this cannot be done by making them `global`. It _is_ possible in many case to arrange for the widget variable (or other data) to be passed to the widget's callback function if needed. If you provide a runnable [mre], someone should be able to show you how to do this…

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to get your text in `Entry` widget when it is writing. Not by pushing a `Button`. please check this if I am right:

```
from tkinter import *

def call(tex):
    print(tex.get())

root = Tk()
tx = StringVar()
tx.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, tex=tx: call(tex))
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=tx)
entry .pack()
root.mainloop()
```